# How do you create a required partitioned table field from a BigQuery query result?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
CREATE TABLE
  mydataset.newtable (transaction_id INT64, transaction_date DATE)
PARTITION BY
  transaction_date
AS SELECT transaction_id, transaction_date FROM mydataset.mytable
```

The docs don't specify whether the PARTITION BY clause supports "required".

Comment: `PARTITION BY` is not required.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean declaring `require_partition_filter` in statement, you should add it in `options` expression:

```sql
create table my_dataset.partitioned_table
partition by dt
options (
  require_partition_filter=true
)
as
select date '2021-06-01' dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make `transaction_date` field required as a usual field